# Save the outlook. mailitem. attachement (doc file) as a text file (sample.txt)

Tags: vb.net, outlook

My question is that I have a mail with a sample.doc file as attachment. I am able to save the mail as "abc.msg" file and even as "abc.txt" format using the below statement.

Dim msg As MailItem

Dim res1

Dim res2

res1 = "C:\temp\abc.msg"

res1 = "C:\temp\abc.txt"

msg.SaveAs(res1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSGUnicode)

msg.SaveAs(res2, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olTXT)

Here my problem is that i want to do the same with the mail attachment also. I want the sample.doc file to be saved as sample.txt file format instead of ".doc". It means that i want to save the document as a plain text file.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanking you in advance.
Haritha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doc into a richtextbox then save the contents of the box as .txt you will have a txt file of the .doc

I will try post some code for you soon but am in work now.

Comment: I am trying to save the attachment as text file and not the mail. can you please help me with some keywords or with little coding?

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as an RTF file, then use the Word Object Model to load the file and save it as a txt file.

Comment: can you please help me with some keywords or with little coding?